# Postgresql copy from file changed rows order

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to save text file content into Postgresql database. First of all I want to copy file into one table with one column in order to iterate over it and save values into specific tables.

I'm using Postgresql version 11.5 on Mac. I copied file into temp table (one line as one row). Then I wrote plpgsql function that iterates over each row of temp table and parses values into other tables. It was working fine on small dataset but when I used bigger one ~ aprox (6*10^5 lines) function failed because it expected specific (same as in file) rows order. After some investigation it turned out that rows order in temp table is different than lines order in the file. What's more interesting first difference occurs on 455864th row.

```
CREATE TABLE "Temp"
(
  data_row text
);

COPY "Temp"(data_row) FROM 'PATH_TO_FILE';
```

I expect COPY FROM command to copy data in same order that is in file.

Comment: Rows in a relational database have no sort order. They represent unordered sets. The database is free to return the rows in any order it likes unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your SELECT statement.

Comment: Have you considered ordering the table before running your function? Perhaps if you show the function we can help you. Relying on insertion order is hardly a reliable approach.

Comment: I'd also add that iterating over rows is almost always a bad idea.  Use the power of SQL to work on sets of data instead of individual rows.

Comment: I thought sorting temp table would be impossible due to column structure but after adding auto-increment id column it became possible and solve my problem! Thank you :)

Comment: How exactly sets of data can do same thing as iterating over rows in order to extract specific values from a row?